# ошибка числа с плавающей точкой в Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

```py
import time
i=0
while True:
    print(i)
    i= i+0.1
    time.sleep(0.1)
    round(i, 1)
```

Comment: в чем ошибка? хотя бы print(round(i, 1)) сделайте...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

результат функции `round` надо чему-то присваивать

```
i = round(i, 1)
```

а не как это сделали вы